# Copying text from PDF file doesn't keep indentation or formatting

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, code, indentation, snippets

I get a problem whenever I try to copy/paste code snippets from a PDF file, the pasted code doesn't keep the indentation which is a big problem in Python.

**This is the source:**

[image]

**Here's what gets pasted:**

> def many_types(x):
>
> if x < 0:
>
> return "Hello!"
>
> else:
>
> return 0

Is there a way to keep the indentation and formatting of the source text?

Comment: Your 'source' is a picture. No-one can test it.

Comment: Of course, I took a snapshot from a PDF file, I can't embed it here. 
You may test with any PDF file you have.

Comment: Works fine for me on some random pdfs, not on others. Without your file or a minimum reproducible example, we have literally nothing to work with. It's probably a formatting issue with the pdf itself, but we can't tell from here.

Comment: Is there perhaps an option to preserve relevant formatting when copying text in your PDF software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF is *Page Description Format*, meaning that the layout is specific for appearance on a specific size page. It does *not* flow text, as does a text editor or word processor, but has hard line breaks. Converting a PDF document to text, or to be used in a word processor, while retaining *some* of the original formatting, is difficult.

There are specialized tools to convert PDF to document formats, and online facilities, such as [PDF to DOCX Converter](https://www.freeconvert.com/pdf-to-docx) or [Zamzar's PDF to ODT converter](https://www.zamzar.com/convert/pdf-to-odt/). You could try dealing with the files these produce, which *might* be better for copying-and-pasting code. Note, though, that you may still need to do considerable hand-editing. Tools to format code *are* readily available, such as the [TextFX plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151200/reformat-code-in-notepad) for [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).